# Pyautogui doesn't recognize own picture what is wrong?

Tags: python, pyautogui

```
im = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(802, 625, 45, 45))
im.save(r"C:\Users\Nanotech\Desktop\zax\boss.png")
if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('boss.png', region=(802, 625, 50, 50)):
    print("test")
```

this is my code and pyautogui doesn't recognize own picture, what is wrong on here ?

Comment: try instead of 'boss.png' r"C:\Users\NanoTech\Desktop\zax\boss.png"

Comment: nope didn't work

Comment: instead of 'boss.png' try using the im itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `confidence=0.9` is solved my problem but I was hoping the program would find it with the `ss` it got itself. A bit of a strange situation.